# Why there is no #define before PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When we want to make a plugin, we need to register the plugin

```
PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(carrot_planner::CarrotPlanner, nav_core::BaseGlobalPlanner)
```

My understanding is that this is the redefinition of the pluginlib_export_class macro. However, from what I have seen so far, we need `#define` for this. How come there is no `#define`?

Thanks,
Rico

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360543/why-there-is-no-#define-before-pluginlib_export_class-macro?/) by [RicoJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/40968/ricoj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2020-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> My understanding is that this is the redefinition of the pluginlib_export_class macro.

Not quite: it's an *invocation* of the macro.

> However, from what I have seen so far, we need `#define` for this. How come there is no `#define`?

Because you're not defining a macro, but invoking it.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RicoJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/40968/ricoj/) on 2020-08-30**:
Good point, but note that there is no semicolon `;` after the macro. My understanding is that when we invoke a macro, there is always a `;`. [Here is an example for a macro with no semicolon](https://docs.ros.org/api/carrot_planner/html/carrot__planner_8cpp_source.html#l00048)

This is interesting

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-08-31**:
This seems like a different (but related) question.

Please post follow-up questions as new questions, instead of as comments under answers to your original question.